# "lambda capture" on regular function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
 void startDrawLoop(function<bool()> func)
        {
        while (func()) {} 
        }

    int main() 
    {
    CubeRenderer cubeRenderer; TextRenderer textRenderer;

    // Do initialization

    auto drawLoop=[&] () 
    {
    cubeRenderer.draw();
    textRenderer.draw();
    return true;
    } 
    startDrawLoop(drawLoop);
    return 0;
    }
```

If I change `drawLoop` to a function.

```
bool drawLoop()
{
// Error, cannot find cubeRenderer
cubeRenderer.draw();
textRenderer.draw();
return true;
}
```

How can I make reference to variables outside the function like what lambda captures do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make `drawLoop` accept arguments and call it from a lambda that does the capture.

```
void startDrawLoop(function<bool()> func)
{
    while (func()) {}
}

bool drawLoop(CubeRenderer const& cubeRenderer, TextRenderer const& textRenderer)
{
    cubeRenderer.draw();
    textRenderer.draw();
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    CubeRenderer cubeRenderer; TextRenderer textRenderer;
    startDrawLoop([&]() { drawLoop(cubeRenderer, textRenderer); });
}
```

You can also use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) but I personally find it ugly compared to the lambda.

```
startDrawLoop(std::bind(drawLoop, std::cref(cubeRenderer), std::cref(textRenderer));
```

If you want to make the call site as simple as possible, you can make `startDrawLoop` a template to accept any function with any arguments.

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void startDrawLoop(F func, Args const&... args)
// [...]
startDrawLoop(drawLoop, cubeRenderer, textRenderer);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e985c295578dd0b)

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I am just wondering if there is a walkaround to get rid of the lambda. It's not very intuitive to use, since `std::function` ideally should accept any callable type.

Comment: Sure but it gets a bit more complex. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent code without the lambda is:

```
struct lambda_t
{
    CubeRenderer &cubeRenderer;
    TextRenderer &textRenderer;

    bool operator()() const
    { 
        cubeRenderer.draw();
        textRenderer.draw();
        return true;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    CubeRenderer cubeRenderer; TextRenderer textRenderer;
    lambda_t drawLoop{cubeRenderer, textRenderer};
    startDrawLoop(drawLoop);
    return 0;
}
```

Whether this is more aesthetic or not is up to you...